# Spark SQL is interpreting a datetime.date object as a mathematical formula or integer in statement

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've encountered a problem in Spark SQL.  It is interpreting a datetime.date object as a mathematical formula, or integer, in a SQL statement I am writing.

```
currentDateAndTime = datetime,now()
current_month = currentDateAndTie.strftime("%m")
current_year = currentDateAndTime.strftime("%Y")

first_day_of_month = date(int(current_year), int(current)month), 1)
print(first_day_of_month)
type(first_day_of_month)
```

and you get:

2022-10-01
datetime.date

Then when I do

```
df = spark.sql("""
SELECT * FROM table_A
WHERE IncidentCreatedDate < {}
""".format(first_day_of_month))
```

I get an error that says AnalysisException:  cannot resolve '(table_A.`IncidentCreatedDate` < ((2022 - 10) - 1' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(tableA.`IncidentCreatedDate` < ((2022 - 10 - 1))' (date and int).;......

There might be a typo in everything above because I had to type everything out on another laptop since the other one is my work laptop and they don't like me sending anything from that laptop to anywhere else.)

Answer (score 1):

pyspark doesn't support prepared statements.

format will replace the pace holder, but strings mus be in single quotes, so simply add them

```
df = spark.sql("""
SELECT * FROM table_A
WHERE IncidentCreatedDate < '{}'
""".format(first_day_of_month))
```

Comment: Can you explain to me how is it possible to compare a date, IncidentCreatedDate, to a string?  Thanks.

Comment: it should run without a problem, the date format from your function returns 2022-10-01 after correcting your code